# Why does delete[] crash this test program

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I declare a **new** array of pointers. *My question is: why does deleting the array with `delete[]` cause the program to crash?* Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int uint32;

struct demon{
    private:
    static uint32 next_id;
    public:
    uint32 id;
    demon(){
        id = demon::next_id;
        demon::next_id++;
    }
};

uint32 demon::next_id = 1;

int main(){
    demon** demons = new demon*[5];
    demon d1;
    demon d2;
    demon d3;
    demon d4;
    demon d5;

    demons[1] = &d1;
    demons[2] = &d2;
    demons[3] = &d3;
    demons[4] = &d4;
    demons[5] = &d5;

    cout << demons[1]->id << endl;
    cout << demons[2]->id << endl;
    cout << demons[3]->id << endl;
    cout << demons[4]->id << endl;
    cout << demons[5]->id << endl;

    delete[] demons; // without this, the code works
    return 0;
}
*** Error in `./test': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000e68c20 ***
Aborted
```

I tested it out for memory leaks as well without the delete and the program will segfault.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41078565/719662 is wrong (actually, it's not an answer at all). Don't accept first answer just because somebody gives it to you... many answers on SO are blatantly wrong.

Comment: actually, your problem is elsewhere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: tl;dr you're allocating and deallocating properly; it's a heisenbug being a result of indexing `demons[5]` at all - if you shift your indexes to proper 0..4 range (`demons[0]`...`demons[4]`), your code works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In C++ containers (arrays/vectors) use zero-based numbering.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) You should use:

```
demons[0] = &d1;
demons[1] = &d2;
demons[2] = &d3;
demons[3] = &d4;
demons[4] = &d5;
```

As it is now, you are writing to an unallocated memory region. This is a common source of extremely complicated error scenarios and therefore you should get familiar with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: I ninja'd you to it, Jonas, but you're still completely right, this is the actual error here: http://ideone.com/mhBqSU

Comment: @vaxquis Funny that I also just changed `demons[5]` to `demons[0]` in my offline test :-) Good edit (adding the link).

Comment: I just noticed that.  Whoops lol thanks for spotting that simple mistake for me.